Disallow user from querying database structure
How can I use SQL Server 2019 Developer edition's permissions to deny the curerntly logged in user from selecting data from the sys.objects, sys.tables, sys.columns, etc. system views, as well as the INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema?
I've tried using DENY VIEW ANY DEFINITION, DENY SELECT ON SCHEMA::sys, DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON DATABASE::<db>, however after all of these I'm still able to perform queries such as SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM sys.columns; without error.
Is there some role functionality or something that could be overriding the permissions I'm trying to set?
Also, is there some way I'd be able to customise the error message produced when an attempt to violate this rule occurs?

The user can access the Metadata of tables etc he has access to. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/metadata-visibility-configuration?view=sql-server-ver16 plus, some objects are usually always visible I guess. Whaäy are you trying to prevent this

@siggemannen trying to prevent other developers from writing code checking for structure in the wrong section of the program basically. Other options exist but I figured DB permissions would be the easiest, I just can't get anything I throw at the wall to stick.

If you disallow all selects from tables, they won't see them. Let's put it this way, if you select one row from table, it reports the Metadata in the columns anyway. What's so bad if developers "writing code checking for structure in the wrong section of the program basically" whatever that means

@siggemannen I'm sure there would be ways to work around it (e.g. as you said, by selecting a row), but my goal is just to discourage the incorrect behaviour. Having that misunderstanding did end up leading to the loss of some customer data during a migration, so I would rather code such as that isn't able to be checked into the code base again.

@AmberCahill it sounds more like code reviews should be part of the process (to prevent repeated customer data loss) rather than this kind of work-around.

usually groups using branching with code reviews to doublecheck and prevent bad code to be merged to dev codeline. so you can capture issues befor merge to dev. depends on which source safe you using there are some known processes for GIT, DevOps, etc..
